# Associations in CakePHP with non-conventional database

Tags: cakephp, associations, database-relations

We are converting an application for use with CakePHP 2.0.3. 
For some reason, I cannot seem to set proper relations between my models.

Here's an example:

- User (id, petid, country, picid, ...)
- Pet (id, userid, picid, ...)
- Picture (id, albumid, ....)
- Album (id, userid, petid, ...)

The meanings of these are the following:
 - A user can have multiple pets, but can only have selected one pet at the same time (therefore, petid in User)
 - Pets belong to one user
 - Pets and Users can have multiple pictures, but only one profile picture, therefore Pet.picid and User.picid
 - Pets and users can have multiple Albums

I set up my models in CakePHP, but I cannot figure out which relations to use between them since the Database is not following the conventions. 
I've tried the following:

- User
  -> hasMany(Pets)
  -> hasOne(Picture)
  -> hasMany(Album)
- Pet
  -> belongsTo(User) (works fine, with foreignkey userid)
  -> hasMany(Album)
  -> hasOne(Picture)
- Album
  -> hasMany(Picture)

---- Logic to achieve this? It either belongs to a user or pet-----

-> belongsTo(User)
   -> belongsTo(Pet)

- Picture
  -> belongsTo(Album)

I'm new to CakePHP and cannot figure out the way to go here.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Aliases](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) in your relationships which will help get your head around the data being returned.

For example, your **User** model could use **SelectedPet** and **ProfilePicture** in it's associations:

User.php model

```
/**
* belongsTo associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $belongsTo = array(
    'SelectedPet' => array(
        'className' => 'Pet',
        'foreignKey' => 'petid'
    ),
    'ProfilePicture' => array(
        'className' => 'Picture',
        'foreignKey' => 'picid',
    )
);

/**
* hasMany associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $hasMany = array(
    'Album' => array(
        'className' => 'Album',
        'foreignKey' => 'userid',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'Pet' => array(
        'className' => 'Pet',
        'foreignKey' => 'userid',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

Your **Pet** model could use **ProfilePicture** as well:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'userid'
        ),
        'ProfilePicture' => array(
            'className' => 'Picture',
            'foreignKey' => 'picid'
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Album' => array(
            'className' => 'Album',
            'foreignKey' => 'petid',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
```

**Picture** model:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Album' => array(
            'className' => 'Album',
            'foreignKey' => 'albumid'
        )
    );
```

..and finally your **Album** model:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'userid'
    ),
    'Pet' => array(
        'className' => 'Pet',
        'foreignKey' => 'petid'
    )
);

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $hasMany = array(
    'Picture' => array(
        'className' => 'Picture',
        'foreignKey' => 'albumid',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

With regards to the logic of an **Album** belonging to a **User** or a **Pet**, you could just handle this in your controller when saving data or returning it. I.e User is given preference over Pet.

I hope this helps.